# Group by not detecting duplicates but there are dupes. Strange SQL Server - Azure Synapse database dedicated SQL pool

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, special-characters, azure-synapse

I have encountered a strange (until I understand the logical reason) behaviour of `group by` in a SQL Server database.
There are many duplicates in a table, for which when I query I get duplicate rows but when I try to find all dupes using group by or `row_number` strategy I get 0 records.
But when I add "Cast" to the group by / row_number I get correct list of duplicates.

The datatype is `nvarchar` for all 3 keys.
Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Added the query and its output

[image]

```
select top 10 len(VBELN) len_vblen, len(MANDT) , len(posnr) ,  * from [SRC_SAP_R3].[LIPS] where VBELN = '6316785926'

select cast(MANDT as nvarchar) as "MANDT",cast(VBELN as nvarchar) as "VBELN" , cast(posnr as nvarchar) as "posnr", count(*) from [SRC_SAP_R3].[LIPS]
group by cast(MANDT as nvarchar),cast(VBELN as nvarchar)  , cast(posnr as nvarchar) 
having count(*)>1;

select cast(MANDT as varchar) as "MANDT",cast(VBELN as varchar) as "VBELN" , cast(posnr as varchar) as "posnr", count(*) from [SRC_SAP_R3].[LIPS]
group by cast(MANDT as varchar),cast(VBELN as varchar)  , cast(posnr as varchar) 
having count(*)>1;

select MANDT, VBELN ,posnr, count(1) from [SRC_SAP_R3].[LIPS]
group by MANDT, VBELN ,posnr
having count(1)>1;
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If we can't replicate this issues it is unlikely we can provide an explanation. Perhaps provide the DDL of your table and some inserts of the data that is giving you these results.

Comment: try DATALEN() instead of LEN()  --- `select top 10 datalen(VBELN) datalen_vblen, datalen(MANDT) , datalen(posnr) ,  * from [SRC_SAP_R3].[LIPS] where VBELN = '6316785926'`

Comment: I have also tried to replicate your issue and it's working fine for me see [image](https://i.imgur.com/IxGJLqB.png)

Comment: I tried with your approach [it](https://i.imgur.com/Y5HhY2g.png) is working fine for me.

Comment: Did you check count(*) also?

Comment: Casting them without length will truncate them to 30 characters. Maybe they have many trailing spaces and differing amounts

Comment: Don't `MANDT, VBELN, POSNR` form the key for the `LIPS` table in SAP ABAP by default? How have you got duplicate keys in there? What modifications have you been making?

Comment: Perhaps azure-synapse is the key here. It might handle stuff differently from regular SQL Server. Looks like a bug to me. Can you post the query plan for the "OK" and "Bad" query?

Comment: I figured it out, it was special char issue. If I do cast to string and group by it works.. n also if I do row_number then also it works..  probably due to diff in coallation between sap n sql server

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this in Azure Synapse Analytics.  As *@Martin Smith* said the **len()** function will ignore the trailing spaces while computing the total length of the column. When I tried with **datalength()** function, the length of trailing spaces is also included. Below is the repro.

- A table is created with varchar column and one data is inserted with trail spaces and other data is without spaces.

```sql
 create  table SAP_TAB (VBELN varchar(100))
insert  into SAP_TAB values('500 ')
insert  into SAP_TAB values('500')
```

- Then len() function, datalength() function is applied to data. Also, casted the data as varchar and length function is applied to casted data. Below is the query.

```sql
select VBELN,len(VBELN) as [length_VBELN],
datalength(VBELN) as [data_length_VBELN],
len(cast(VBELN as  varchar(10))) as 
[length_varchar_casted_VBELN]
from sap_tab
```

**Result**

| VBELN | length_VBELN | data_length_VBELN | length_varchar_casted_VBELN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| 500 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

[image]

Comment: len will ignore the spaces.. but it will not work with special characters not detected by sql. len() was giving same result in value.